# CSS apply type selector to another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So here's my use case, I've some headers in an old application I'm refurbishing that are out of order. Trying to be 508 compliant, I'm trying to change the headers to be incremental (therefore changing the first header from a h3 to an h1, the second one from an h3 to an h2 and so on).

Now, the headers were used as selector for the CSS rules. Seeing as the rules are applied throughout the application, I'd prefer not to change them. Therefore, my question is, can I apply CSS rules from one header type, to another? For instance, can I've a specific h1 use the h3 css rules kind of like a class?

Comment: The very last sentence is confusing. Can you rephrase it? If you are wondering about something like an inheritance system, it's not part of the CSS standard, though you could use Sass for that.

Comment: I edited it, my headers were being read as code.

Comment: I think he means if he can still somehow use the standard `h3` styling for his `h3` headers which are now `h1` (so he wants an `h1` header with `h3` styling). Without manually setting all the rules for all the different headers.

Comment: No, what you want can only be achieved using css classes.

Comment: Can I create a class that applies existing rules? like a class called h3rules that will just apply all rules used on h3 elements?

Comment: Please add your existing markup and styles to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with just CSS or extension. What you're basically asking is whether you are able to do something like:

```
h3 { inherit: h1 }
```

You will have to use [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/guide) or something similar to achieve this.

An alternative would be using a script like:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(h1, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
alert(theCSSprop);
```

Looping through all possible css styles and then adding that styling as a css file or setting it as a style directly. But like you probably already noticed, this is not a manageable solution and you should only use it as a last resort.

Best thing you can do is just add a class and do the styling that way.